# Comparar parámetro (int) con Record

Tags: java

Teniendo la siguiente clase LeaderBoard:

```
public class LeaderBoard{

    private final int maxScores;
    private List<Score> scores;
    private static final String FILE_LEADERBOARD = "leaderboard.ser";

 public LeaderBoard(int maxScores) {
        if(maxScores<=0){
            this.maxScores=5;
        }else
        this.maxScores=maxScores;
    }


    private List<Score> getScores(){
        try (ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(FILE_LEADERBOARD))){
            return (List<Score>) input.readObject();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            return new ArrayList<>(this.getMaxScores());
        }
    }

}
```

Siendo Score el siguiente Record:

```
public record Score(String name, int points) implements Comparable<Score>, Serializable{

    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 13L;

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return name+": "+points+" pts";
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Score o) {
        int result=0;
        if (this.points>o.points) {
            result = -1;
        }
        else{
            result = 1;}

        return result;
    }
}
```

He de programar en la clase LeaderBoard el siguiente método:

```
public boolean isInTheTop(int points) {}
```

El cuál devuelve true si los puntos introducidos por parámetro son suficientes para estar en el top del leaderboard, es decir, entre las 5 mejores puntuaciones.

Tengo el siguiente esqueleto:

```
public boolean isInTheTop(int points) {

        for (Score score : scores) {
            return points >= score.points;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

¿Cómo podría continuar? ¿Habría que usar el método compareTo del Record Score?

Comment: ¿Qué debería hacer el método `isInTheTop`? ¿Devolver `true` si `points` es mayor que algún puntaje del LeaderBoard y false en otro caso? Actualmente cómo lo tienes simplemente compara el primer resultado. El `for` no tiene ningúna función ahí.

Comment: Debe devolver true si points son suficientes para estar en leaderboard, es decir en las primeras 5 posiciones. Edito la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualmente solo estás comparando el primer elemento de la lista y directamente devuelves `true` o `false` sin recorrer toda la lista con el `for`.

Agrega un `if` que pregunte si los puntos son mayores, si no, que siga al siguiente. Si terminó, y no encontró ningún puntaje mayor, simplemente devuelve `false`:

```java
public boolean isInTheTop(int points) {
    for (Score score : scores) {
        if (points >= score.points()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

Teniendo en cuenta que la lista de Scores pueda tener más de 5 elementos, entonces es conveniente obtener el top5 y luego comparar. El método quedaría:

```
public boolean isInTheTop(int points) {
    List<Score> top5 = scores.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
            .limit(5)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    for (Score score : top5) {
        if (points >= score.points()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Su respuesta sería correcta si se busca comprobar si es la puntuación más alta pero hay que comprobar si es suficiente para estar entre las 5 mejores puntuaciones. ¿Sería conveniente ordenar de mayor a menor la lista antes de realizar el for? Es decir: scores.sort(Collections.reverseOrder()); Por otro lado, se me ocurre crear una nueva lista que sea similar a la lista obtenida por getScores() , método el cuál devuelve ya la tabla de las 5 mejores puntuaciones y comparar con esta.

Comment: @NoVa ahí edité mi respuesta.

Comment: En cuanto pueda comprobarlo marco si es correcta, gracias.